# is it possible to user ternary operator in firebase rules function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to use dynamic path based on user's id in the firebase rules function does firebase rules support this approach.

```js
function externalNestedProfessionalKeysCreate(requestResource) {
  let requiredFields = ['id', 'name', 'days', 'metaData','dragAndDrop',  'subNote'];
  let optionalFields = ['sectorSplit'];
  let allFields = requiredFields.concat(optionalFields);
  let path = request.auth.token.userType == 'user' ? 'data-user-professional' : 'data-admins-professional'

  return requestResource.keys().hasOnly(allFields) && 
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(path)/$(userId)/clients/$(clientId)).data.colCount <= 2
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `request.auth.token.userType` just doesn't contain the value you expect?  If the rules language didn't support this syntax ([it does](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#logical-operators)), then you wouldn't be able to submit this code at all, and it would fail to compile.